# Navigation Controller Back Button is there two times

Tags: button, controller, navigation, back

Solved!

I have a Navigation Controller in my project, when I click on a Button to show a detailView it works great. But when I click on "Back" in the detailView, it only changes the title of the back button to my title in the first view controller. So i have to click two times on the button to get back. 
I saw the solution somewhere on a Youtube video a few months ago but I don't remember :/
It would be awesome if anybody could help :)

Comment: Hello are you doing some king of customization on your back button? Can you please provide some sample code from your project so we can better understand your issue?

Comment: @Ali
I've got an ViewController from where I push a second VC with "pushViewController"

I also have a Navigation Controller, so there is a "back" button on the second VC. But when I click this back button, it looks like it goes back, but the view stay the same, only the back button change his title to the title of my first ViewController. When I click on this button again, it goes back to my first VC. So i have to click two times on the back button.

Comment: Do you have two navigation controllers embedded?

Comment: All in all i've got 3 Navigation Controllers, but only one for this. So it doesn't really matter. And yes, i've got an customized back button, but the problem stays, when i I don't customize it.